# Python Find Difference Between Two Custom Class Sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two Products sets A and B, Product is my custom class.
How can I find all products in set A meet the following criteria?

> a.link == b.link and a.date != b.date

```
A = set([Product('link1', '02-08-2018'), Product('link2', '01-01-2018'), Product('link3', '02-02-2018')])
B = set([Product('link1', '01-08-2018'), Product('link2', '01-01-2018'), Product('link4', '02-02-2018')])

# HOW?? I want get Product('link1', '02-08-2018') and Product('link3', '02-02-2018') back here
result = A - B

class Product:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.link= data['link']
        self.date= data['date']

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.link+self.date)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.link == other.link and self.date == other.date
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with this code? `list(Product)` will definitely fail in the first line.

Comment: @zvone Updated my case, sorry for the confusion. basically, I just want to get the difference between these two sets

Comment: Side-note: The canonical method for hashing is to rely on `tuple`'s hashing functionality (which is more general and optimized to get a good hash distribution; making small tuples is highly optimized in Python, so the construction cost is trivial). `return hash((self.link, self.date))` would be both efficient and correct for most potential use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `A.difference(B)`

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, link, date):
        self.link= link
        self.date= date

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.link+self.date)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.link == other.link and self.date == other.date

A = set([Product('link1', '02-08-2018'), Product('link2', '01-01-2018'), Product('link3', '02-02-2018')])
B = set([Product('link1', '01-08-2018'), Product('link2', '01-01-2018'), Product('link4', '02-02-2018')])

result = A.difference(B)
```